# gcov does not generate coverage files

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcov

I am cross compiliing my executable for coverage using -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage flags on a 32 bit machine .  And the resulting executable I am running it on target machine which is 64-bit.

When I run the executable it does not generate .bb .bbg and .da files. What can be the reason for it.

Comment: Can we see at least command lines you are using for compilation/linking?

Comment: As I am running the exe on different machine gcov is creating the complete directory hierarchy where object files were located in host machine which I am not aware of and gcda files are located in this directory.

Comment: 1) I don't get your comment, but I'd very much appreciate your commandlines. 2) Can you try it without cross-compilation?

Answer (score 2):

Most probable reason is that the data files are generated in the same directory as the compile which may not be accessible on, or not writable from, the target platform where the test is executed.

With decently recent gcc version, environment variables GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP can be used to override the default directory.

Comment: You are my hero. Such an obvious---but easy to overlook---solution.